# Frequency of value in Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash, dictionary

If I have a hash of book ratings like

```
books = {"Gravity's Rainbow"=>:splendid,
         "House in Hyde Park"=>:splendid, 
         "The Week"=>:quite_good
        }
```

and I want to count the number of occurrences of a particular value, or rating, how is this done?

I tried `books.values[:splendid].length` - but I suppose the error is brought about because it thinks I want to slice everything up to "splendid", which is of the wrong type, from "books.values".

How do I remove everything not ":splendid" from `books.values`? Should I be looking at list operations rather than hash? I'm totally new to Ruby, thinking as I type. I'm not sure if `books.values` has returned a list or some other type though?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`books.values` returns an array:

```
books.values
#=> [:splendid, :splendid, :quite_good]
```

So you can just use [`Array#count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-count):

```
books.values.count(:splendid)
#=> 2
```

Or something like this to count all values:

```
Hash[books.group_by { |k, v| v }.map { |k, v| [k, v.count] }]
#=> {:splendid=>2, :quite_good=>1}
```

Comment: What would be code change for following hash, hash = {a: 5, b: 2, c: 3, d :5} and the output for value 2 should be 1 (=> 1), value 5 should be 2 (=> 2) ?

Comment: @avidCoder there won't be any code change, it's the same problem. Although nowadays you could simply use `hash.values.tally`

Comment: This is what I have used -  def value_count(hash, value)
    Hash[hash.group_by { |k, value| value }.map { |k, value| [k, value.count] }]
end . but output it shows is 2. I want result in this format - {5=>2, 2=>1, 3=>1}

Answer (score 4):

Using Enumerable's [#count method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count):

```
books.values.count { |v| v == :splendid }
```

As @Stefan answered, you can also shorten it by just `books.values.count(:splendid)`